# Automatic Headphone Control Issues

Tags: audio, control, microphone, iphone, headphones

A friend wants an automatic headphone controller for his bike. According to the [Android spec](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec) we should be able to add a bias resistor of 5kohm between mic and ground, short mic to ground for play/pause or short to some resistance for volume up/down.

Play pause works perfectly fine, but I can't get the proper resistance for volume up/down which is a necessary feature. We can't add a stereo potentiometer into the line because of the form factor.

This is our current circuit.

[image: My current setup]

We have attempted replacing R1 and its FET with a potentiometer and button to quickly test other resistances with no luck. We are testing with an iPhone running iOS 14.2 with a lighting to 3.5 mm adapter.

Are we thinking about this all wrong? Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: *According to the Android spec* (this applies to Android phones!) but then *We are testing with an iPhone*. There is no reason to assume that an iPhone will work in the same way as an Android phone is supposed to work.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, I agree. I looked for specs for iPhones and didn't turn up much. I kept looping back to the Android spec. That combined with the play/pause function still working makes me think my resistances just aren't right. If you know of any better iPhone specific resources, I'll gladly pour through them... but I can't find them for iPhone